# Not catching on simple proofs set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Schaums Outlines Abstract Algebra there's the following definition:

$A - B = \{x | x \in A, x \notin B \}$

(a)

Prove $A - B = A \cap B' = B' - A'$

Answer: $A - B = \{x|x\in A, x\notin B \} = \{x | x\in A  \land \in B' \} = A \cap B' =\{x|x \notin A', x \in B' \} = B' - A'$

Okay, not too bad.

(b)

Prove $A - B = \emptyset \iff A \subseteq B$

Answer: Suppose $A - B = \emptyset$. Then by (a), $A \cap B' = \emptyset$, i.e., $A$ and $B'$ are disjoint. Now $B$ and $B'$ are disjoint; hence, since $B \cup B' = U$, we have $A \subseteq B$.

The last sentence is where I have trouble following. My guess is that what they're trying to say is that if $A$ and $B'$ are disjoint, and $B$ and $B'$ are disjoint, $A$ must therefor equal $B$. The last part, *since* $B \cup B' = U$, *we have* $A \subseteq B$, does not make sense to me. What does $B \cup B'$ have to do with $A \subseteq B$? Isn't it what I just said, that $A$ equals $B$? So why state it like $A \subseteq B$ and not $A = B$?

As probably can be deduced from my entry level question, if it is possible, please ELI5!

Comment: I find the books proof very problematic, since they are using the concept of a universal set, that is, the set $U$ is the set that contains everything in your universe of discourse (everything you are willing to consider), yet the way they defined set-theoretic difference does not actually require that concept (the notion of complement used herein does however require a universal set).

Comment: That is interesting. I find that these kind of things put up road blocks for me, as I'm autodidact. At one point you're handling the material well, the other you're stumped.

Comment: That's an almost unavoidable part of self-study (and indeed research activity) in mathematics, going from clarity one moment to confusion the next (and back again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I find the given answer really bad. It says several technically correct things, but seems to make leaps just as large as what the question is actually asking. The idea is that because $B \cup B' = U$, the entire set, and $A \cap B' = \emptyset$, then everything that lies inside $A$ must lie inside the part of $U$ that is made up of $B$ (since none of it can lie inside $B'$).

Here is an (in my opinion) better proof:

Suppose first that $A - B = \emptyset$. Now take arbitrary $a \in A$. Then, since $a \notin \emptyset = A - B$, we must have that $a \in B$, for otherwise $a \in A - B$. Thus, $A \subseteq B$.

Conversely, suppose that $A \subseteq B$. Suppose (towards a contradiction) that $A - B \neq \emptyset$; then there is $a \in A - B$. That is, there is $a \in A$ with $a \notin B$. But this contradicts that $A \subseteq B$. Thus $A - B = \emptyset$.

If you have difficulty picturing this, I strongly suggest you draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: So it wasn't me after all. It makes sense now, bedankt!